# Почему intellij не может найти аннотацию @Max?

Tags: java, аннотации

Разбираюсь с аннотациями. Хочу указать аннотацию `@Max`. Делаю так:

```
    @Max(2)
    int i = 3;
    System.out.println(i);
```

Но IDEA не определяет эту аннотацию и показывает ошибку. Почему? 
Хотя с тем же `@NotNull` все правильно.

Comment: потому что она не из стандартной jdk ?

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov и что делать?

Comment: Проверьте импорты.

Comment: я бы скачал jar библиотеки с этой анотацией и поставил в проект

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov я хотел использовать maven, поискал в mvnrepo, но ничего не нашел

Comment: @talex да вроде все нормально с импортами, идея разве сама не импортирует что надо?

Comment: оно ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/ESBTR/max.html

Comment: @ValentineAnzhurov нет, причем тут дб?

Comment: откуда эта аннотация ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91395/discussion-between-valentine-anzhurov-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/… --> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId> 
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```